# Swift - Not Parsing JSON Data

Tags: ios, json, database, swift, tableview

I am trying to build a simple iOS swift app to parse some data from a web-based JSON file and fill up a Table View with it, but it is not working. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ProdutoresTableVIewController: UITableViewController, NSURLConnectionDelegate {

var data : NSMutableData = NSMutableData()
var produtores = [produtor]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.fetchProdutores()
    print(String(produtores.count))
}

func fetchProdutores(){
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:3000/producers.json")
    let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    let connection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)
    connection?.start()
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return produtores.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    if let rowData: produtor = self.produtores[indexPath.row] as produtor{
        cell.textLabel?.text = rowData.name
    }
    return cell
}

func connection(didReceiveResponse: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse){
    self.data = NSMutableData()
}

func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didReceiveData data: NSData){
    self.data.appendData(data)
}

func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection){
    do{
        if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSArray{
            let counter = jsonResult.count
            for i in 0...counter - 1{
                let prod = produtor(name: "name",isActive: true,id: 0)
                let prodItem : NSDictionary = jsonResult.objectAtIndex(i) as! NSDictionary
                prod!.isActive = (prodItem["active"]!) as! Bool
                if prod!.isActive{
                    prod!.name = (prodItem["name"]!) as! String
                    prod?.id = (prodItem["id"]!) as! Int
                    print(String(prod!.id) + " " + prod!.name)
                    produtores.append(prod!)
                }
            }
        }
        }
    catch{
        print("Something went wrong =/")
    }
}


}
```

It looks like the code reads the data, since it it displayed at the console after some *print* commands. However, the table view remains empty after *viewDidLoad* method finishes running. Do you have any answer for this? Thanks!!!

Comment: It looks to me like you are always creating new table cells and you never use the deque function

Comment: You need to reload your tableview after the data has finished loading.

Comment: It works!!! Thank you very much for the answers!!!